# php reg expression to check date format is correct

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently trying to find out if a date is in the format of `YYYY-DD-MM`.

In PHP, I've got this:

```
if (preg_match('(\d{4})(-)(\d{2})(-)(\d{2})$', $newDateOfBirth))
```

However I keep getting the following error:

> Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '(' in
>   C:\webserver\webroot\index.php on line 105

Comment: Off-topic tip, I recommend using [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) or [checkdate()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) to validate that the dates are valid. @mario you can edit comments instead of re-posting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the delimiters:

```
if (preg_match('~(\d{4})(-)(\d{2})(-)(\d{2})$~', $newDateOfBirth))
```

Comment: The `$` needs to go inside the delimiter